# Using a string to reference an object name

Tags: javascript

I'm trying to replicate a "feature" of PHP (And in most languages) in Javascript.

Here it is in PHP:

```
$objectName = 'ObjectA';

$someObject->$objectName->someMethod();
```

Basically using a string variable to reference an object variable.

So in Javascript, I was hoping to do something like:

```
var objectName = "ObjectA";

someObject.[objectName].someMethod();
```

Anyone know how to do this? Or if its even possible?

Answer (score 14, accepted):

You almost have it, just remove the first `.`, like this:

```
var objectName = "ObjectA";
someObject[objectName].someMethod();
```

If you want to search for more info around this, it's called [bracket notation](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Member_Operators#Bracket_notation).

Comment: Gah. I was one damn character off. I didn't know what it was called or I would've Googled Bracket Notation.

Thanks a lot!

Comment: This does not work beyond depth one. If you have a string like "Object.a.attribute.val" you cannot object[str] the last attribute. How to achieve this?